# Magento 2 - How to override less file of third party module @ view/base/web/css/source?

Tags: magento2, theme, styles

I try to override this file from my theme:

```
vendor/amasty/module-mega-menu-lite/view/base/web/css/source/module/frontend/_base.less
```

I placed it at:

```
app/design/frontend/company/fresh/Amasty_MegaMenuLite/base/web/css/source/module/frontend/_base.less
```

but it does not get overriden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this correct path to override less file:

app/design/frontend/company/fresh/Amasty_MegaMenuLite/web/css/source/module/frontend/_base.less

After created above path redeploy and cache flush as well.